# Separate Keywords at comma and semicolon

Tags: stormcrawler

I am indexing website with keyword metatags that are separated at comma as well as semicolon, I see Storm Crawler's CommaSeparatedToMultivaluedMetadata setup separates keywords at comma, but how do I separate keywords at semicolon first, and if no semicolons are present, then by comma?

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by the name of the parsefilter, it operates on commas only. It should be fairly easy to write a modified version of this class to implement the logic you need.

Comment: Would it be possible to add this in the parsefilter itself in your code? I see many sites that use ";" instead of "," as a separator when Keywords and Author Names for example already have a comma in them.

Comment: Any contributions to the project are welcome. Feel free to open a pull request to improve this functionality